# I got a problem during the pull request in GitHub

Tags: git, github

I am having trouble with pull request and merge  in GitHub.

I would like to merge the "CommitA" of "ExBranch" into the "Dev" branch after receiving code review.

So, firstly, I had pushed the "CommitA" to the "ExBranch". 
After then, I asked 'Pull request' for code review (Dev <= ExBranch). 
While waiting the review process for the "CommitA", I pushed another commit of "CommitB" to the "ExBranch" without pull request.

The reviewer reviewed the code and approved merge "ExBranch" to "Dev".

In here, the problem was occurred. Even though I had intended to merge the "CommitA" into the "Dev" branch, the reviewer's approval had allowed that not only "CommitA" but also "CommitB" was merged to the 
"Dev" branch.

Do you have any solution to prevent merging the Commit which is pushed after 'pull request' ?
Please help me~!

Comment: Pull requests are about branches, not specific commits.  You shouldn't push additional commits to a PR branch unless you intend for them to be part of the PR.  Can you unstage Commit B and stash it and then revert CommitB from ExBranch?

Answer (score 0):

> While waiting the review process for the "CommitA", I pushed another commit of "CommitB" to the "ExBranch" without pull request.

Any commit pushed to a branch involved with a PR will update that PR to include said commit.

If you need to push a new commit, create a new branch from your current `ExBranch`, and push that commit on that new separate branch, which is not involved yet in a Pull Request.